# cannot convert type 'diaryEntry' to system.datetime

Tags: asp.net, datetime

In my diaryEntry tab;e I have id, siteId and date. I pass a date through and I want the list 'DiaryEntry' to store all the dates that match.  I then pass this list through a foreach which should then highlight the dates on screen on a calendar.

```
 DateTime tempDate = System.Convert.ToDateTime(Session["Diary_Date"]);
        DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(tempDate.Year, tempDate.Month, 1);
        DateTime endOfMonth = startOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
    List<Diary_Entry> DiaryEntry = new List<Diary_Entry>();

        DiaryEntry = (from DE in db.Diary_Entries
                      where DE.Site_Id == 1
                      && DE.Date >= startOfMonth && DE.Date <= endOfMonth
                      select DE).ToList();


  foreach (DateTime d in DiaryEntry)//list is name of list you use avoue(in linq)
        {
            Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(d);//CALENDAR 1 IS WHAT I CALLED IT IN ASPX
        }
```

ERROR: ecannot convert type 'diaryEntry' to system.datetim

Can someone possibly advise me how to resolve this that ye

Comment: You should show us class Diary_Entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
foreach (DateTime d in DiaryEntry)
```

`DiaryEntry` is `List<Diary_Entry>`, not a list of `DateTime`.

Change to:

```
foreach (Diary_Entry d in DiaryEntry)
```

And now for each `d`, you can access its `DateTime` members.

Answer (score 1):

```
  foreach (var d in DiaryEntry)
        {
            Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(d.Date); //assuming d.Date is a datetime
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have list of Diary_Entry, not DateTime, so if you want to iterate through datetime enumerable, you should get it. You can use linq to do this:

```
    foreach (DateTime d in DiaryEntry.Select(de=>de.Date))
    {
        Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(d);//CALENDAR 1 IS WHAT I CALLED IT IN ASPX
    }
```